# Все даты недели

Tags: дата, calendar, java

Элементарный вопрос: как получить все даты текущей недели. Была мысль найти дату понедельника, но это тоже не могу сделать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например, так:

```
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTime(new Date()); // Устанавливаем текущее время
    calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.MONDAY); //Устанавливаем понедельник на календаре, будто сейчас понедельник

    for(int i = 0; i < 7; i++){
        System.out.print(calendar.getTime()); 
        calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, 1); //Прибавляем сутки
    }
```

Comment: Хорошее решение, спасибо.